# Custom home not working when console run manually (cygwin)

Tags: console, cygwin

I was trying to set a new home directory for Cygwin, but the thing is I've managed to do so only partially.

I changed the 'db_home:' parameter (cygwin64/etc/nsswitch.conf) to '/windows' so it now matches the win10 default home folder, but the trick works only if mintty.exe was run through cmd.

Running mintty manually with a desktop shortcut results with the very same default directory as if the file was never changed.

Having all that said, I'm a total newbie when it comes to both Cygwin and Unix in general, so it's very likely I missed something obvious.

I appreciate any help provided, thanks in advance.

Comment: In general is it better to leave the two home directories separated. Cygwin use ACL (file permissions) in a particular way to emulate posix file permission and windows default setting (also inherited) could interfere.

Comment: Thanks for the information. With that in mind, I think I'll restore the default state.

Comment: Did you mean `/windows` or just `windows`?

Comment: '/windows', as stated in the OP.